# Make One AsyncTask Wait For Another One To Complete?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two Asynchronous tasks each one in a separate class, I can call them in the main thread, simply using:

```
 new RetrieveTask().execute();
 new RetrieveTaskImageData().execute();
```

But I want the first one to finish before starting the second.

This is an example of one of them:

```
class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Void> {
private Exception exception;
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        //Code here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.exception = e;

    } finally {
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute() {
    //
}
}
```

How can we achieve this?

**EDIT**

Can we use `new RetrieveTask().execute().getStatus()==..Finished` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be achieved automatically because unless you call [`executeOnExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)), all `AsyncTask`s [run on the same thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#order-of-execution), so two of them can not run concurrently.

Comment: Thank you, what is the reference for this?

Comment: @TiyebM google documentation, order of execution: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#order-of-execution

Answer (score 0):

I'have 4 async tasks in my main thread and have if statement inside 2 of them, if one works, other one stops. I did removecallback and execute just inside tasks for eachother, worked for me. (i am using kotlin but i think same should work with java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to impelement interface on first AsyncTask and onPostExecute it will callback to main thread. you need to call second AsyncTask  on that override callback method.